# To Add multiple logics while matching the file

Tags: excel, vba, automation, formula

In Column A, B and C I have raw data, I need to first find if a particular file with particular date and particular status is available in raw data or not, if it is not available it can come with answer 0 or Dash. And if it is available I need to add logics to get the correct answer.

1. If a particular File with particular Date is available and if it is meeting the criteria in Column C it can return with the answer "Available"

**The Criteria is**
In column C for that particular file if it founds the word "Combine" and/or "Part 1 and Part 2" and/or "Part 2 and Combine" than it should return with answer "Available"

2. For that particular file in Column C if it founds only "Part 1" or only "Part 2" it should display with answer "Not available"

This way i can get if both parts of a particular file is available or not. please see the screenshot

[image: Example]

I hope i am able to clarify the question. I will be thankful for this.

| Date | Name of File | Status of File |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20-Jan-23 | North | Combine |  |  |  |
| 20-Jan-23 | South | Combine |  |  |  |
| 20-Jan-23 | East | Combine |  |  |  |
| 20-Jan-23 | West | Combine |  |  |  |
| 20-Jan-23 | Alpha | Combine |  |  |  |
| 20-Jan-23 | Beta | Combine |  |  |  |
| 20-Jan-23 | Gama | Combine |  |  |  |
| 21-Jan-23 | North | Part 1 |  |  |  |
| 21-Jan-23 | North | Part 2 |  |  |  |
| 21-Jan-23 | South | Part 1 |  |  |  |
| 21-Jan-23 | East | Part 2 |  |  |  |
| 21-Jan-23 | East | Combine |  |  |  |
| 21-Jan-23 | West | Part 1 |  |  |  |
| 21-Jan-23 | Alpha | Part 1 |  |  |  |
| 21-Jan-23 | Beta | Part 1 |  |  |  |
| 21-Jan-23 | Beta | Part 2 |  |  |  |
| 21-Jan-23 | Gama | Combine |  |  |  |

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Dear @Ike I have tried to add logics but could not add, stuck at the formula =IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(1,(F3=$A$3:$A$20000)*(G2=$B$3:$B$20000),0)),"Available","Not Available")

Comment: Can you post your sample data as text - best using [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) (read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16578424) for an explanation). Which version of Excel do you have?

Comment: I have 2016 version

Comment: @Ike I have tried to put the tables into the question, can you please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function in G2:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$18=E2)*($B$2:$B$18=F2)*($C$2:$C$18 = "Combine")),"Available",
IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$18,E2,$B$2:$B$18,F2,$C$2:$C$18,"Part *")=2,"Available","not available"))
```

[image]

Comment: Dear @IKE i will check and revert

Comment: Dear @IKE i appreciate the logic you have added, Thank you so much,

Comment: Please give me a favor. the formula is extracting perfect status. However just one problem.... You know if for a particular File if in the raw data there are part 1 and part 2 the result will be "Available" similarly if in the raw data there are "Part 1" and "Part 2" two times for a particular publication it gives "Not Available" is there any solution. please